# Zabbix Server crash. No connection to mysql, no log files and no system process

Tags: mysql, linux, logging, monitoring, zabbix

our Zabbix Server is running (*service zabbix-server start*: Job is already running: zabbix-server) and our MySQL Database is running, too.

But the dashboard of the Zabbix Server gives the following information:

"Zabbix Server is not running".

Furthermore there is no Zabbix-server process when I check the processes in the server machine with "*ps aux | grep zabbix*".

Moreover there a no log files.

Last day I edited the zabbix-server.conf and changed the "*MaxHousekeeperDelete*" from "500" to "200".

Note: This command isn´t working when in the init.d folder: "./zabbix-server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf"

Can someone help?

King regards :-)

Zabbix Version: 3.2

SYSTEM: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.19.0-69-generic x86_64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if there is a .pid file for zabbix on the system and delete it.
Then try to start the server again.

This should be a comment but don't have enough rep to do so.

EDIT:
Can you ensure the `nscd` is running with `ps aux| grep nscd`? If not install it with `sudo apt-get install nscd`

EDIT2:
Also can you please ensure that you have set **START=yes** in `/ets/default/zabbix-server`

Comment: thanks for your fast responese. delete the pid file does not help. still no log file by the way ...

any other idea? :)

Comment: i just installed nscd but nothing changed. still can´t start that server.

Comment: this setting was already set but i changed it to "no" for a fast test. with the "no" setting i receive a process id for "service zabbix-server restart". with "yes" setting i´ll get no process id. 

but both variants lead to no process when typing "ps aux | grep zabbix"

I am open to other suggestions ^^

Comment: The START should be definitely set to yes. Without it you won't be able to use the start script to run the server. Can you also confirm that `/var/run/zabbix` exists and is owned by zabbix `chmod -R zabbix:zabbix /var/run/zabbix` ?

Comment: You should have some logs at this stage in `/var/log/zabbix-server` that will tell you more ?

Comment: Yes I can confirm.

Our server was working until i changed the MaxHousekeeperDelete value in the server config file. I think the problem is the mysql server because in some older logs from the zabbix server is printed that the zabbix server can´t connect to the mysql server: "database down" and "43245:20161005:120953.071 [Z3005] query failed: [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) [select hostid,key_,state,evaltype,formula,error,lifetime from items where itemid=118862]"

ps: no logs

Comment: In that case all i can suggest is tho run the binary with `strace`. `strace /usr/sbin/zabbix-server` and update your question with output. Sorry!

Comment: i never used strace. do you have the right parameter for me? :)

Comment: i copied the output but it is 23 pages long (in word) ..

How should i sent it to you?

Comment: EDIT1: https://1drv.ms/w/s!AqnDkhf32L-9gSPtB8VBYcmi4Y64 

It´s OneDrive

Comment: Ok. Error from the output: `write(2, "unknown parameter \"HistoryTextCa"..., 98unknown parameter "HistoryTextCacheSize" in config file "/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf", line 360) = 98 `. Check that line and either comment it out or check the proper syntax. Also, the `strace` output suggest to me that your logging should be working.

Comment: an anonymous company thanks you :D 

thanks. everything is working now. even the logs

Comment: hey KrisTheSavage. today we got a problem like a week ago. the server is running but all hosts are unreachable. the error log tells me:

Comment: failed to accept an incoming connection: from "12.34.56.78".  reading first byte from connection failed: [104] Connection reset by peer. Zabbix agent item "service.info[COMSysApp,state]" on host "hostname" failed: first network error, wait for 15 seconds. resuming Zabbix agent checks on host "DTMVDA01": connection restored